# Phonegap 3.0 - plugin not found (iOS)

Tags: ios, phonegap-plugins

I got the following issue: I'm upgrading an old Phonegap 2.7 project to Phonegap 3.0 but one of the plugins isn't found.

The error from PhoneGap:

```
ERROR: Plugin 'SoundPlug' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 117] FAILED pluginJSON = [
  "SoundPlug1195442045",
  "SoundPlug",
  "getVolume",
  [

  ]
]
```

The config.xml in the www-root:

```
<feature name="SoundPlug">
    <param name="ios-package" value="SoundPlug" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<feature name="SocialSharing">
    <param name="ios-package" value="SocialSharing" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```

The problem lies with SoundPlug, the SocialSharing doesn't give any warning (or that's because it fails on SoundPlug who is loaded first).

In SoundPlug.h:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@interface SoundPlug : CDVPlugin

- (void) setVolume:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
- (void) getVolume:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;
```

@end

In SoundPlug.m:

```
#import "SoundPlug.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@implementation SoundPlug

- (void) setVolume:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    MPMusicPlayerController* musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
NSInteger volume = [(NSString *)[command.arguments objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
    //musicPlayer.volume = 1; // max volume
    //musicPlayer.volume = 0; // min volume (mute)
    musicPlayer.volume = volume * 0.0625; // 1 bar on the overlay volume display
    NSLog(@"Volume set to %f", musicPlayer.volume);
}

-(void) getVolume:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    MPMusicPlayerController* musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
    CDVPluginResult* result = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsDouble:musicPlayer.volume];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:result callbackId:command.callbackId];
}

@end
```

For what it matters: the platform is iOS7.
I recreated the project from scratch and imported the files.

Comment: Ive gotten similar issues with the splash screen and in app browser for iOS. What I ended up doing was just deleting the project and adding it again then everything worked out fine

Comment: I managed to get it working by adding the plugins to the config.xml *outside* the www directory, so the one directly in the root of the project. Still have to wait until I can mark this as correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by adding the plugins to the config.xml *outside* the www directory, so the one directly in the root of the project. I guess I mistakenly used the wrong config.xml